# Flutter/Swift macOS app, how to set the NSWindow cornerRadius?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, flutter, cocoa

I want to change the corner radius of NSWindow for my macOS app. I use flutter to develop the app, I know I need to write some Swift code to complete it, but I do not know how to start.

I want to make my app with a custom corner radius just like CleanMacX.
[image]

It is obvious that the top right corner radius is customed.

Here are what I have.

AppDelegate.swift

```swift
import Cocoa
import FlutterMacOS

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

MainFlutterWindow.swift

```swift
import Cocoa
import FlutterMacOS

class MainFlutterWindow: NSWindow {
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController.init()
    let windowFrame = self.frame
    self.contentViewController = flutterViewController
    self.setFrame(windowFrame, display: true)

    RegisterGeneratedPlugins(registry: flutterViewController)
    
    super.awakeFromNib()
  }
}
```

Comment: You just use `NSView` to customize the shape of the window.

Comment: @ElTomato I am a newbie to Swift, could you give me more details about how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are a novice, do your homework, first.  Run a search.  Hint: Borderless window.